# JavaScript convert string to object contains ":"

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dictionary

I have the following string `var xx = "website:https://google.com";` I'm trying to convert to dictionary `{website:"https://google.com"}` usually I use `str.split(":")`   but here I have multi `:` I can use replace function but what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: `{website:https://google.com}` is invalid syntax...

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries, they're called *objects*.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get `{website: "https://google.com"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const strToDictionary = kColonV => {
  const tmpArray = kColonV.split(':')
  const k = tmpArray.shift()
  const v = tmpArray.join(':')

  return {[k]:v}
}

var xx = "website:https://google.com";
strToDictionary(xx) // Object { website: "https://google.com" }
```

Or, perhaps just:

```
const toDictonary = str => { return {[str.split(':')[0]]:str.substr(str.indexOf(':')+1)} }
toDictionary(xx) // Object { website: "https://google.com" }
```

There's a lot of ways you could phrase this.

```
class Dictionary extends Object {};

const kvToDict = str => Dictionary.assign( // No need to do this, but it's interesting to explore the language.
  new Dictionary(),
  {[str.slice(0, str.indexOf(':'))]:str.slice(str.indexOf(':')+1)}
)

const kvDict = kvToDict("website:https://google.com")
console.log(kvDict.constructor, kvDict) // Dictionary(), { website: "https://google.com" }
```

I like this one:

```
const kvToObj = str => Object.assign(
  {},
  {[str.slice(0, str.indexOf(':'))]:str.slice(str.indexOf(':')+1)}
)
kvToObj("website:https://google.com") // Object { website: "https://google.com" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the first occurrence of `:`.

```js
var xx = "website:https://google.com";
xx = xx.split(/:(.+)/);
var dictionary = {[xx[0]]:xx[1]};
console.log(dictionary);
```